# QGIS: How to extend functionality of "Export to PostgreSQL" algorithm to allow not only overwriting but to TRUNCATE & APPEND

Tags: qgis, postgresql, modelbuilder, qgis-processing, toolbox

*** If my question ist not suitable here, were can I post it? ***

In the QGIS process modeler, I'm missing a process for uploading a vector layer to a PostgreSQL database by means of TRUNCATE and APPEND to an existing table. This would preserve the security settings and priviledges set for this table.

At the moment, QGIS only has an algorithm in the toolbox for *Export to PostgreSQL* with the only option to overwrite the existing table (or alternatively, to throw an error). I opened the Python script for this algorithm and found out that it is of course using the QGIS API class *QgsVectorLayerExporter* to achieve this.

```
options = {}
if overwrite:
    options['overwrite'] = True
if convertLowerCase:
    options['lowercaseFieldNames'] = True
    geomColumn = geomColumn.lower()
if dropStringLength:
    options['dropStringConstraints'] = True
if forceSinglePart:
    options['forceSinglePartGeometryType'] = True

# Clear geometry column for non-geometry tables
if source.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.NoGeometry:
    geomColumn = None

uri = QgsDataSourceUri(conn.uri())
uri.setSchema(schema)
uri.setTable(table)
uri.setKeyColumn(primaryKeyField)
uri.setGeometryColumn(geomColumn)

if encoding:
    options['fileEncoding'] = encoding

exporter = QgsVectorLayerExporter(uri.uri(), providerName, source.fields(),
                                  source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs(), overwrite, options)
```

How do I write a process script to reproduce and extend the functionality of the PostgreSQL uploader?

Ideally, the PostgreSQL Export algorithm can provide three options:

If table already exists in database:  [Drop-down selection]:

- DROP and CREATE
- TRUNCATE and APPEND
- APPEND

I could imagine that this extended functionality might be useful not just for me but to other QGIS users as well.

Since I don't have any Python coding experience, I have no clue how to achieve this.

Comment: You could use the plugin [Append Features to Layer](https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer/#append-features-to-layer), which allows you to append/update features in your target layer. Once installed, it gives you an `AppendFeaturesToLayer` algorithm.

Comment: Enhancement requests should go to the development team.